# location of chromedriver in the latest version of webdriver-manager

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, protractor, webdriver-manager

I have recently updated to the newest version of webdriver-manager (v. 12.0.4) and now get this error whenever I try to start my webdriver:

```
/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium does not exist, run webdriver-manager update
```

In the older version of webdriver there was a selenium directory that contained chromedriver and the new version does not have a selenium directory at all and my grunt task does not know where to find chromedriver now.

Does anyone know what the location is of the chromedriver in the new version of webdriver-manager?

Answer (score 1):

In the error message it says that you will need to run `webdriver-manager update`. Running update will create the folder `/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium`. After it creates the folder it will download the binaries including the chromedriver binary. In your project you will run something like: `/node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update`.

Comment: Thanks, should that be done in the global node_modules dir, or in the one specific to protractor, ie `node_modules/protractor/node_modules`?

Comment: You could use the global installation of webdriver-manager as long as you plan to just use `webdriver-manager start`. If you are using Protractor with `directConnect: true` or starting it "local" (no configuration provided so Protractor starts/stops your selenium standalone server on your behalf), then you need to use the project's node module.